# Angular Testing, dynamically change ActivatedRoute params for different test cases

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-test

Component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html'
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  useCase: string;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(p => {
      if (p) {
        this.useCase = p.u;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Test Spec

```
describe('TestComponent', () => {
  let component: TestComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        AppModule
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: ??? }
      ]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    expect(component.useCase).toBeFalsy();
  });

  it('should set useCase variable with query string value', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    // Set different route.queryParams here...
    expect(component.useCase).toBe('success');
  });
});
```

Using Angular 6, Karma and Jasmine for unit testing.

I know we can set `ActivatedRoute` to an object that will be used through out this testing, as such:

```
providers: [
  { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: {
    queryParams: Observable.of({id: 123})
  } }
]
```

But this will set the values for all the test cases. Is there a way to dynamically change the `ActivatedRoute` in each different test case?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can get it with `TestBed.get(ActivatedRoute)` in your **it** functions if you want to stock it in a variable. You can update value also.

From Karma v9.0.0 at the angular's newest versions the `TestBed.get` method is deprecated

Comment: Thanks Suresh! That works. It's as simple as `TestBed.get(ActivatedRoute).queryParams = of({ id: 1 });`

Comment: you're a genius ^^ haha

Comment: In Angular 14 (for example) use `TestBed.inject` in place of `TestBed.get`.

Answer (score 2):

Credit to Suresh for the correct answer, and to update it slightly as of Angular 9 `TestBed.get` is deprecated.  The recommended approach is now

```
let activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute;
...
activatedRoute = TestBed.inject(ActivatedRoute);
activatedRoute.snapshot.params = { foo: 'bar' };
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are not using `testBed` then use this line of code:

in the `beforeEach` method, the `activatedRoute` mock should be defined as follows:

```js
activatedRoute = {queryParams: of({id: 1})};
```

then in your it method, update the activatedRoute to:

```js
activatedRoute.queryParams = of({id: 2})};
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative with a stub class. Follow bellow the approach.

Declare a stub class

```
class ActivatedRouteStub {
    private _params = new Subject<any>();

    get params() {
        return this._params.asObservable();
    }

    public push(value) {
        this._params.next(value);
    }
}
```

In your beforeEach declare an alias for the activated route provider

```
beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                RouterTestingModule
            ],
            declarations: [YourComponentComponent],
            providers: [
                {
                    provide: ActivatedRoute,
                    useClass: ActivatedRouteStub
                }
            ]
        })
            .compileComponents();
    }));
```

And you can use it anywhere you desire. Bellow example in "it" test.

```
it('should show example, how to set parameters', () => {
        let spy = spyOn(router, 'navigate');
        
        // here we pass the any parameter for return and type the route variable with the stub class
        let route: ActivatedRouteStub = TestBed.inject<any>(ActivatedRoute);
        // you can push the parameters like you desire.
        route.push({id: 0})

        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['not-found'])
    });
```